# написать уравнение прямой, проходящей через точку пересечения прямых и через точку

Tags: математика

написать уравнение прямой, проходящей через точку пересечения прямых 3x+y-6=0; x-2y+5=0 и через точку M(-4;2)

Comment: Напиши. Что мешает?

Comment: 3x+y-6=0 - это уравнение одной прямой. Нужно найти где потерялось второе уравнение, потом решить эти два уравнения как систему - полученное решение (x, y) будет точкой пересечения прямых. Дальше нагуглить как получить уравнение прямой по двум точкам, подставить эти точки - это и будет решением. Все просто.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, поскольку причина закрытия заданий "учебные задания надо решать самому" [отменена](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9743/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/9774?noredirect=1#comment40703_9774), решим...

Из первого уравнения y = 6-3x. Подставляя во второе, получаем x-12+6x+5 = 7x-7=0, откуда x=1. Из первого уравнения y=6-3=3.

Уравнение прямой, проходящей через точки (1,3) и (-4,2)? понятно, (x+4)/(1+4)=(y-2)/(3-2), или y = (x+14)/5...

Comment: Она не отменена. Мы теперь просто минусуем и отправляем ТС в "question ban". + тут явный оффтопик

Comment: Как вариант предложу ещё один неплохой способ - если есть два уравнения прямых, то уравнение любой прямой, проходящей через точку их пересечения, может быть получено как линейная комбинация двух исходных уравнений. Берём теперь два коэффициента a, b , и пишем общее уравнение прямой, проходящей через точку пересечения: a (3x+y-6) + b (x-2y+5) = 0, подставляем вместо x, y координаты требуемой точки x = -4, y = 2, получаем уравнение на a, b, подбираем любое его решение. Это может иногда оказаться полегче, чем честный поиск координат пересечение, хотя по сути то же самое :)